# Density of C^\infty in the domain of the exterior derivative on a noncompact, complete manifold?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, regularity, approximation-theory, exterior-algebra

Let $(M,g)$ be a geodesically complete Riemannian manifold that is not necessarily compact. Futhermore, assume that $M$ has at most exponential volume growth (ie., locally doubling property). Let $\mu$ be the volume measure.

Does anyone know of a reference for the density of $C^\infty(\wedge T^\ast M)$ in $D(d) = \{u \in L^2(\wedge T^\ast M): du \in L^2(\wedge T^\ast M)\}$.

Here, the $L^2$ space is defined as:

$L^2(\wedge T^\ast M) = \{u:M \to \wedge T^\ast M\ |\ \int_{M}\ (u(x),u(x))_x\  d\mu(x) < \infty\}$

where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the canonical extension of the metric $g$ to the exterior algebra.

Comment: Is every element of $C^\infty$ in $L^2$? I guess not.

Comment: Do you mean $C^\infty$ with compact support ?

Comment: Sorry. I should really have said $C^\infty \cap L^2$. But you're right, $C^\infty$ with compact support is good enough (in fact, better!)

Comment: I should say that I'm also quite open to changing my definition of $L^2$. In fact, in "Spin Geometry" by Lawson & Michelsohn, they define $L^2(\wedge T^\ast M)$ to be the completion of $C_c^\infty(\wedge T^\ast M)$ in the $L^2$ norm. This may infact be better, because it's not obvious to me that $C_c^\infty$ is in fact even dense in the $L^2$ I've defined above. 

Comment: Are you asking how to show this or do you already know how to do it but want a reference to cite? Do you know the answer for functions?

Comment: Hebey has a book (called Sobolev Spaces on Riemannian Manifolds) where he includes a proof (for functions) that $C^\infty_c$ is dense in $H^1$ (i.e. functions in $L^2$ and with gradient in $L^2$.  The argument is a simple one with cutoffs and presumably works in your case as well.  (interestingly the density fails for higher sobolev spaces without imposing curvature conditions).

Comment: What you want is essentially in M P Gaffney's paper in the
Annals of Math vol 60 no 1 .

Comment: Yang: I don't know how to do it, but I'm certain it should be true. In fact, in the book "Spin Geometry" by Lawson and Michelsohn, they assert that this is true, but their seem to assume $d = d_\infty$ in the setup I've given in a couple of comments below. I'm horrible at finding references and I was hoping someone would know it!


Comment: RBega: You are talking about Theorem 3.1 on page 49. He does not give a proof of it there. He simply says that it's a Theorem of Aubin. I'm just wondering if you actually saw this argument in the book? If so, could you please tell me where you saw it?


Comment: (Continued...)

The sobolev space $H^1$ is constructed as the completion of $C^\infty \cap L^2$ in the graph norm of $\nabla$. My setup is slightly different (and please correct me if there is a better way of doing this). Let $d_c$ be the exterior derivative with domain $C^\infty_c$ and $\delta_c$ also have domain $C^\infty_c$. These maps are related by

$(d_c u,v) = (u, \delta_c v)$.

Defining the $L^2$ spaces as the completion of $C^\infty_c$ as above), we have that $\delta_c$ and $d_c$ are densely defined. 

Comment: (Continued...)

Therefore, by a theorem of Kato, these operators are closeable and let the closure be denoted as $d_\infty$ and $\delta_\infty$. Certainly, since we've taken the closure of these operators, $C^\infty_c$ is dense in the graph norm.

Now, I can also just take $\delta_c$ and ask for the adjoint of $\delta_c$ which I'll just denote as $d$. That is, we want $d$ to be the operator with largest domain $D(d) \subset $L^2$ such that
$(\delta_c u, v) = (u, dv)$ for $v \in D(d)$.



Comment: (Continued...)

My question then can be phrased operator theoretically as: Is $d = d_\infty$. But note that unlike the Sobolev spaces which are the completion of $C^\infty \cap L^2$ in the graph norm of $\nabla$, my operator $d$ does not come from such a completion.

Comment: Mohan: I'll look for that paper! Thanks. 